# Firebase - How to permanently save user profile?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Firebase Console only allows to set email address and password, there is no option to save user's profile but this can be done using code:

```
user.updateProfile({
   displayName: "Chinmay Sarupria"
}).then(function() {
   console.log(user.displayName);
}, function(error) {
   console.log(error);
});
```

If this is the way to save user data permanently then it is impossible to write code for every user just to save their displayName like this or is doing via code permanent, at the moment it is working for me but I'm not sure if it will remain like that forever.

Ofcourse, I could save the user data in realtime database and then fetch it based on user's uid but if saving user data in the user variable is possible then that is much better than getting the data from database.

Answer (score 0):

After you reference your user object you can update values under the UID for that user.

```
var rootRef = new Firebase('https://yourapp.firebaseio.com');
// Check the current user login status and redirect if not logged in
var user = rootRef.getAuth();
if (user) {
  var user = rootRef.getAuth();
  var userRef = rootRef.child('users').child(user.uid);
  ... do something with the logged in user...
}

function writeData () {
  var user = rootRef.getAuth();
  var userRef = rootRef.child('users').child(user.uid);
  var profileRef=userRef.child('profile').push();
  profileRef.update ({
    name: "Tony",
    position: "Developer"
  });
};
```

This should give your user profile a structure something like this:

```
}
  "users" : {
    "067f75bf-4a07-473e-82e5-d9a5ee11be17" : {
      "profile" : {
      "-KN2dG5X4lLpp0fwfsXK" : {
        "name" : "Tony",
        "position" : "Developer"
      }
    }
  }   
}
```

Note the push() function gives you the randomly generated key.  You may not need it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please don't store user profiles under push keys. Unless there is a need for multiple nodes per user under `/users/$uid/profile`, you should just store the data as `/users/$uid/name`, `/users/$uid/position` etc.